# Optimizing JOIN with UNION is not working

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query :

```
SELECT * FROM foo f1
JOIN foo f2 ON f1.ID = f2.ParentID or f1.ID = f2.ChildID
AND f2.CreateTime > 'YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00.000'
```

I tried to optimize it to get better performance so I wrote :

```
SELECT * FROM foo f1
JOIN foo f2 ON f1.ID = f2.ParentID
AND f2.CreateTime > 'YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00.000'

UNION

SELECT * FROM foo f1
JOIN foo f2 ON f1.ID = f2.ChildID
AND f2.CreateTime > 'YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00.000'
```

But I am getting different results! Any idea why?

Thank you!

Comment: To get an answer that doesn't involve huge assumptions, please show sample data that demonstrates what you *mean* by ***different***.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question is `WHY are the results different`.

```
SELECT * FROM foo f1
JOIN foo f2 ON f1.ID = f2.ParentID or f1.ID = f2.ChildID
AND f2.CreateTime > 'YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00.000'
```

Should have been written

```
SELECT * FROM foo f1
JOIN foo f2 ON (f1.ID = f2.ParentID or f1.ID = f2.ChildID)
AND f2.CreateTime > 'YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00.000'
```

Spot the difference.  Check **[OPERATOR PRECEDENCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx)** (i.e. `AND` before `OR`)

The second one equates to the below.

```
SELECT * FROM foo f1
JOIN foo f2 ON f1.ID = f2.ParentID
AND f2.CreateTime > 'YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00.000'
UNION
SELECT * FROM foo f1
JOIN foo f2 ON f1.ID = f2.ChildID
AND f2.CreateTime > 'YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00.000'
```

The first equates to

```
SELECT ...
JOIN foo f2 ON f1.ID = f2.ParentID
-- **condition missing
UNION
SELECT ...
JOIN foo f2 ON f1.ID = f2.ChildID AND f2.CreateTime > 'YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00.000'
```

Comment: +1 : Good spot.  The `AND` being on a new line tricked me into thinking of it as a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: I actually figured that out and was just going to answer the question :) That was it actually and the results I was getting in the first query where wrong. The intended optimization fixed the data as well!

Answer (score 0):

UNION will join both result set and remove duplicates. Try union all

```
select 1 as ID
UNION 
SELECT 1 as ID
```

result 1

```
select 1 as ID
UNION ALL
SELECT 1 as ID
```

result 1 and 1